# particle sphere only displaying as straight line in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm learning to use the *THREE.js* library by creating a particle sphere inside my *React* App. Referencing [**this**](https://codepen.io/discoverthreejs/pen/LQLQRd) project, I've managed to get *somewhat* of a start, but am at a bit of a dead-end.

For some reason, despite the fact that all my code is essentially the same - except for some deprecated methods being swapped out - *THREE* will render a weird straight line every time.

After looking at the documentation for a few hours and trying to learn the individual methods of this component, I'm still scratching my head.

This is what I have (a live version can be viewed [**here**](https://codepen.io/akroda/pen/abVRppO)):

```
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
const vector3D = new THREE.Vector3();

// Get constraints of the canvas.
const getConstraints = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Get attribute-set width and height - defaulting to computed constraints.
  return [canvas.width ?? width, canvas.height ?? height];
};
// Retrieve a random point in the sphere for a particle to be set at.
const getRandomPointInSphere = radius => {
  const x = THREE.MathUtils.randFloat(-1, 1);
  const y = THREE.MathUtils.randFloat(-1, 1);
  const z = THREE.MathUtils.randFloat(-1, 1);

  const normaliseRatio = 1 / Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

  vector3D.x = x * normaliseRatio * radius;
  vector3D.y = y * normaliseRatio * radius;
  vector3D.z = z * normaliseRatio * radius;

  return vector3D;
};

// Initialisation methods.
const initScene = () => {
  const [canvasWidth, canvasHeight] = getConstraints();
  // Renderer initialisation.
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
    antialias: true, alpha: true,
  });
  renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  // Scene initialisation.
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Camera initialisation.
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(100, 0, 100);
};
const initPoints = () => {
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const positions = [];

  const particleSize = 0.2;
  const particleColor = 0x1826e0; // Dark blue 
  const particleCount = 50000 / (particleSize * 10);

  for(let i = 0; i < particleCount; i++){
    let vertex = getRandomPointInSphere(50);
    positions.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
  }

  geometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

  const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size: particleSize, color: particleColor });
  const particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  scene.add(particles);
};

initScene();
initPoints();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I'm very new to *THREE* (and canvases in general), so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the line with camera instantiation has to be like this: `camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 1000);`, there is the slash instead of comma.

And then, camera has to look at the scene's center, thus `camera.lookAt(scene.position);`

Snippet with fixed code:

[image]

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" />
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
// THREE variables
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
// Get constraints of the canvas.
const getConstraints = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Get attribute-set width and height - defaulting to computed constraints.
  return [canvas.width ?? width, canvas.height ?? height];
};
// Retrieve a random point in the sphere for a particle to be set at.

const getRandomPointInSphere = radius => {
  v3.randomDirection();

  const normaliseRatio = 1 / Math.hypot(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);

  v3.setLength(radius * normaliseRatio);

  return v3;
};

// Initialisation methods.
const initScene = () => {
  const [canvasWidth, canvasHeight] = getConstraints();
  // Renderer initialisation.
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
    antialias: true, alpha: true,
  });
  renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  // Scene initialisation.
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Camera initialisation.
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(100, 0, 100);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
};
const initPoints = () => {
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const positions = [];

  const particleSize = 0.2;
  const particleColor = 0x1826e0; // Dark blue 
  const particleCount = 50000 / (particleSize * 10);

  for(let i = 0; i < particleCount; i++){
    let vertex = getRandomPointInSphere(50);
    positions.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
  }

  geometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

  const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size: particleSize, color: particleColor });
  const particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  scene.add(particles);
};

initScene();
initPoints();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you mate! Can't believe I missed that first one. But the `lookAt` method was a useful method to learn :-)